# How to use rmvlogis in package ltm to simulate rasch model data?

Tags: r

I try

1. use rmvlogis(in package ltm) to simulate data with 40 rasch items and n examinees
2. use above data and rasch(in package ltm), fix first 14 items parameter as known, to estimate parameters of remaining 26 items.

My code is:

```
library(ltm)
test<-function(n,m) {
  # for reproducible
  set.seed(12345)
  # generate 40 rasch item parameters
  b<-rbeta(40,1.2,1.5)*4-2
  # generate abilities of n examinees
  latents<-rnorm(n,1.5,1.5)
  # construct thetas for rmvlogis, rasch model with discrimination =1
  thetas<-cbind(b,1)
  # generate response data of m examinees with latents
  data<-rmvlogis(m,thetas=thetas,z.vals=latents,IRT=FALSE,link="logit")
  # estimate parameters of items 15-40, use items 1-10 as anchor
  model<-rasch(data=data,constraint=cbind(c(1:14,41),c(b[1:14],1)),IRT=FALSE,start="random")
  # compare b and model$coef[,1]
  plot(b[1:14],model$coef[1:14,1],xlab="b",ylab="bhat")
  abline(a=0,b=1)
  points(b[15:40],model$coef[15:40,1])
}
```

I expect the estimate should be good. But

1. the result of execute `test(300,301)` is good as I expected, scatter plot of real parameters and estimates scatter around the identity line y=x.
2. the result of execute `test(300,300)` is very BAD, I think.
3. according to document about rmvlogis in ltm, I thought I should use `test(300,300)`, why the result is BAD? What I am wrong?

By the way, my OS is Windows 7, R is 3.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your model returns very different things when `m!=n` is because the `rmvlogis` function ignores `z.vals` when the length of `z.vals` and `n` (which you called `m`) are not equal. Look inside the function `rmvlogis` and you will see this line:

```
z <- if (is.null(z.vals) || length(z.vals) != n) {
    switch(distr, 
         normal = rnorm(n), # Your case.
         logistic = sqrt(3)/pi * 
         rlogis(n), `log-normal` = (rlnorm(n) - exp(0.5))/sqrt(exp(2) - 
         exp(1)), uniform = runif(n, -3.5, 3.5)/sqrt(7^2/12))
}
```

So, if `m!=n` (in your function) this will lead to `length(z.vals) != n`, so your `z.vals` argument is completely ignored, and is replaced by a normal distribution with a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1.

So, your "good" results only happened when one of your parameters was ignored. But, my question is, why would you expect the dots to all fall on the line when you have set the mean of the normal distribution of your `latents` to 1.5? If you set them to zero, you will get this result. Below, I modify your function slightly to colour the constrained and unconstrained points, and so that you can manually set the mean of the normal distribution from which you draw your latents:

```
# Modified function
test<-function(n,m,latent.mean) {
  set.seed(12345)
  b<-rbeta(40,1.2,1.5)*4-2
  latents<-rnorm(n,latent.mean,1.5)
  thetas<-cbind(b,1)
  data<-rmvlogis(m,thetas=thetas,z.vals=latents,IRT=FALSE,link="logit")
  model<-rasch(data=data,constraint=cbind(c(1:14,41),c(b[1:14],1)),IRT=FALSE,start="random")
  plot(b[1:14],model$coef[1:14,1],xlab="b",ylab="bhat", col='blue',main=paste('Latent mean:',latent.mean))
  abline(a=0,b=1)
  points(b[15:40],model$coef[15:40,1],col='red')
}

# PLot the three
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
test(300,300,latent.mean=1)
test(300,300,latent.mean=0)
test(300,300,latent.mean=-1)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

As expected, the responses are pushed up or down dependent on the mean of the `latent` distribution. Perhaps you meant to set the `mean` to zero?

Comment: @hjyanghj I don't understand what you mean. Do you mean that you want the latent mean to be zero? If so, change `latents<-rnorm(n,1.5,1.5)` to `latents<-rnorm(n,0,1.5)`

Comment: My scenario is: Form A has 40 items, among them 14 items are old items and their difficulties had been calibrated before. Now, form A are administrated with the hope to calibrate those 26 new items. The ability level of examinee who take form A are unknown and need to be estimated also. So I need calibrate those 26 items even latend.mean is equal 1.2 or something else. Thanks for your response. very appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am unfamiliar with the statistics used in item response and testing. I thought my answer would help you understand the output of your function. You will need to seek help elsewhere for non-programming related questions.